# Reactjs : How to route to another form on submit and send submitted data to the new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help. I have created three form class, Employee, Address and Authentication. Inside the Employee form when the user click the submit button, I want it to go to the Address form page and also send the Employee form data to the Address form page. I know that I can put all this on one page, but it will make it hard to read the code. And I am trying to make it match with my backend (spring boot). ***initialState*** is a Json an I am importing it from another file if your wondering.

**Code for the Employee class**

```
class Employee extends Component {
state = initialState;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

handleChange = event => {
    const {formData} = this.state;
    this.setState({
        formData: {
            ...formData, // leave other values unchanged
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value, // update the changed value
        }
    });
}

validate = () => {
    const {formData, errors} = this.state;
    const {firstName, lastName, email, dataOfBirth, phoneNum} = formData;
    let {firstNameError, lastNameError, emailError} = errors;
    if (!firstName) {
        firstNameError = 'First name can not be blank'
    }
    if (!lastName) {
        lastNameError = 'Last name can not be blank'
    }
    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        emailError = `${email} is not valid email`
    }
    if (!dataOfBirth) {
        console.log(dataOfBirth.length)
        dataOfBirthError = 'Enter a valid date of birth'
    }
    if (!phoneNum) {
        phoneNumError = 'Enter a valid phone'
    }
    if (!validatePhoneNumber(phoneNum)) {
        phoneNumError = 'Enter a valid phone number'
    }


    if (firstNameError || lastNameError) {
        this.setState( {
            errors: {
                firstNameError, lastNameError, emailError,
                dataOfBirthError
            }
        })
        return false
    }
    return true
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const isValid = this.validate();
    if (isValid) {
        this.setState(initialState)
        this.props.push("/addressForm")
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container_fluid">
            <div className="registration_form_container">
                <div className="register_context">
                    <form action="" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="registration_form">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"
                                   placeholder={"Enter first name"}
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                            <span>{this.state.errors.firstNameError}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"
                                   placeholder={"Enter last name"}
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                            <span>{this.state.errors.lastNameError}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"
                                   placeholder={"Enter email address"}
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                            <span>{this.state.errors.emailError}</span>
                        </div>
                
                        <div className="form-group custom_btn_container">
                            <input type="submit" className="btn" value="Register"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Employee;
```

**Code for the Address Class**

```
class Address extends Component {

state = initialState;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

handleChange = event => {
    const {formData} = this.state;
    this.setState({
        formData: {
            ...formData, // leave other values unchanged
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value, // update the changed value
        }
    });
}

validate = () => {
    const {state, city, street, zipcode} = formData.employeeAddress;
    let {firstNameError, lastNameError, emailError, dataOfBirthError, phoneNumError} = errors;
    let {employeeAddressError: {streetError, stateError, cityError, zipcodeError}} = errors
   
    if (!street) {
        streetError = "Street can not be blank"
    }
    if (!city) {
        cityError = "Street can not be blank"
    }

    if (streetError || cityError || stateError) {

        console.log(dataOfBirth)
        this.setState( {
            errors: {
                employeeAddressError: {
                    streetError,
                    cityError,
                    stateError,
                    zipcodeError
                }
            }
        })
        return false
    }
    return true
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const isValid = this.validate();
    if (isValid) {
        this.setState(initialState)
    }
}

render() {
return (
    <div className="container_fluid login_form_main_container">
        <div className="address_context">
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="street" id="street"
                       placeholder={"Enter street address"}
                       onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <span>{this.state.errors.employeeAddressError.streetError}</span>
            </div>
      
            <div className="form-group custom_btn_container">
                <input type="submit" className="btn" value="Register"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
}

export default Address;
```

**In App.js**

```
return (
  <Router>
      <div className="App">
          <Header />
              <div className="content">
                  <Switch>
                      <Route path="/register" component={Employee} />
                      <Route path="/login">
                          <Login Login={LoginDetail} error={error} />
                      </Route>
                      <Route path="/addressForm" component={Address} />
                      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                  </Switch>
              </div>
      </div>
  </Router>
);
```

***Inside the header page***

```
export default function Header () {
return (
    <div className="container_fluid">
        <div className="navbar_container">
            <div className="logo_container">
                <h2>Logo</h2>
            </div>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="links_container">
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/department">Department</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/register">Register</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: Best way to send data from one class to other class other than  props is context api... https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html ....... RECOMMENDED USING FUNCTIOAL COMPONENT EVERYWHERE  FOR MORE READABLE CODE

Answer (score 1):

As told in comment , best way of doing so is context api and here is a small demo of context

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-bardeen-co2op)

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const ActualContext = createContext();

const Contextt = (props) => {
  return (
    <ActualContext.Provider>
      {props.children}
    </ActualContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default Contextt;
```

This is the way for creating a context , sandbox code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the redirect router redirect feature to pass props https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/to-object

Comment: But router cannot pass large amount of data like a image src

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good way to send form data on router parameters and just for readability of the code no need to add another router, I suggest using state managements like [`Redux`](https://redux.js.org/) or `Context API` as [react says](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or if you do not want either of them just add another component for example named `EmployeeForm` and add `Employee` and `Address` component to it (for better UI/UX you can switch between forms as user want) and pass data like this in `EmployeeForm`:

```
class EmployeeForm extends Component{
 handleSubmit = values => {
  this.setState({employee: values})
 }
 render() {
  <Address employee={this.state.employee} />
  <Employee onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
 }     
}
```

then use `this.props.employee` at `Address` component. It is event better implementation if the forms are very related and user can go back and forth as submitting without losing the states of any of these two components.